# Running WPF C# application on Win XP Home Edition

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have an application in WPF C#, compatible to run in Win XP with .NET 4.0. I solved a problem of running installing .NET 4.0 and a update of .NET 4.0 at the moment of installation, everything works very fine in Win XP Professional, but the software don't works at Win XP Home edition.  Apparently have the same packages (SP3), any suggestion that how can i search for a solution ? The program don't Logs anything, the only hint that i have is a Error Event present in the system.

**Log Message**

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID:. 1026
Date: 02/09/2015
Time: 09:30:17
User: N / A
Computer: GB1-C0139
Description:
Application: TestSat.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
Stack:
   at TestSat.MainWindow.butConSerial_Click (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl (System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent (System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick ()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick ()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk (System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler (System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler (System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs (System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk (System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler (System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler (System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl (System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl (System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent (System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent (System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea ()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput (System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput (System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput (IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage (IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher (System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal (System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run (System.Windows.Window)
   at TestSat.App.Main ()


For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: You need to turn on fusion logging.  Use your favorite search engine to learn more about this.

Comment: @Will, the fusion logging is not enable in this version. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Will I can't find the path HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion in this installation.

Comment: Here's the deal.  There are plenty of tutorials for how to configure fusion logging and get it working out there on the internets. It's up to you to go find them.  Suggest reviewing two or three that are on msdn.com.  If you can't manage this, you need to consider alternative lifestyles.